# Old Freebase MQL Read query not working in new Google API

Tags: freebase

Here is an example of an old mqlread query using api.freebase.com that returned some results:

```
https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?queries={"q0":{"query":{"/common/topic/article":[{"id":null}],"name":"Ethanol","type":"/medicine/drug"}}}
```

However, using the new Google API (www.googleapis.com) this query returns an empty result object:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{"/common/topic/article":[{"id":null}],"name":"Ethanol 1","type":"/medicine/drug"}]
```

There isn't any documentation on moving an app to the new API because I'm thinking it should be pretty straight forward. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Yes the observation is correct .. it does not work with the old one anymore .. It happened to me too ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would changing the name of the topic that you're looking up count as "something obvious?"  It's "Ethanol" in your old query and "Ethanol 1" (which doesn't exist) in the new query.

BTW, the BLOB API hasn't been carried over to the new API, so if you want to use the article ID that you're fetching, you'll need to use the new Text API.

Here is the corrected URL and the resulting text API call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{%22/common/topic/article%22:[{%22id%22:null}],%22name%22:%22Ethanol%22,%22type%22:%22/medicine/drug%22}]&indent=1
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/m/02qw8
```

EDIT: p.s. There's one more change in the wind here, although it's not fully formalized yet http://markmail.org/message/tjfmhbb3thd5aqrt

Comment: Unbelievable. I don't know how that "1" got in there but yes, I get results now. And +1 on the knowing what I was going to do with the article Id and saving me some time there! Thanks!

Comment: You are also mentioning there are no docs on moving an app to the new API - we have some docs here http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API - what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API tells us that the old one has been deprecated . 
30 October 2012 was supposed to be the last date ..It has stopped working well before the date..

I tried the query below to see everything that starts with E. I could not find the entity you are looking for. The query is right, may be the entity is no longer in that domain.

```json
[{
  "/common/topic/article": [{
    "id": null
  }],
  "name" :[]
  "name~=": "E*",
  "type": "/medicine/drug"
}​]​
```

Comment: Correct, which is why I'm moving to the new Google API. However, the same query doesn't work on the new API...

Comment: The old API has been deprecated, but it has *NOT* stopped working yet.